# Making a created (programmatically) viewController Rotate

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller

I have made a viewController programmatically and I want to force it to rotate whenever the device is rotated .
in simple viewController you create using the normal way by adding a new file and so there a "shouldAutoRotate" method ..
but in my case it's different especiall that I create this viewController in a viewController!

and I don't want to create a new viewController.

this is the code I used to create the viewcontroller

```
UIViewController *featuresViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"featrures" bundle:nil];
[featuresViewController setView:[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 380, 450 )]];
[featuresViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

featuresViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;      

featuresViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:featuresViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier to add this as another answer...

Probably not the best place to do this, but if you're struggling on how to code your FeaturesViewController, it'll be something like this -

.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FeaturesViewController : UIViewController {
    // ivar declarations...
}

@end
```

.m -

```
#import "FeaturesViewController.h"

@implementation FeaturesViewController

-(id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"FeaturesViewController" bundle:nil];

    if (self) {
        // other init stuff
    }

    return self;

}


-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // return YES for whatever orientations you want
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Then in your main VC, present it like this -

```
FeaturesViewController *featuresViewController = [[[FeaturesViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

featuresViewController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;      
featuresViewController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

[self presentViewController:featuresViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: thnx alot for you effort" I appreciate it" ,, I'll vote you up but its not what  I wanted (I did not want to create new .h and .m files simply)..
thnx again

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in you application...

//add following line before @implementation

```
@interface UIDevice (UndocumentedFeatures) 
 -(void)setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation animated:(BOOL)animated;
-(void)setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
@end

//here you can use following code in any method..i just used here in sample method... 
-(IBAction)rotateviewprogramatically
{
   **//you can also add this in Viewdidload or Viewwillappear...it will work...**

   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
   //or
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
 }
```

**// Change following code....** add following method in you code...i checked it's working...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);// don't use this
return YES; // use this...

}
```

Hope, it will help you...chill

Comment: thnx man ,but I  can't get it work with my viewcontroller ,actually I don't get it !!... can you add more details ..thnx alot

Comment: @MoathOthmanAliwat: I have changed code...use it..i tested and it worked..let me know if it won't work...

Comment: will this code works even I see its undocumented (so maybe apple will refuse it ,right?)
and  again thats not what  I wanted  :(( maybe my question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean when you say you create the viewController in a viewController - I think where you create it is irrelevant. It's also irrelevant that you create it programmatically, as you still have to have written the code...

In your VC's code, simply implement the normal shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method (this example allows either of the landscape orientations) -

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: Well, I have a viewcontroller with .h and .m and .xib files called"Setting" ok ... and one of the buttons another view is created as I mentioned above and called by [self performModalViewController:featuresViewController animated:yes];
thats it But if you tried to rotate the device when featureviewcontroller   in the top simply it doesnot!!!
I hope you get it ..So the shouldAutoRotateTo... wont work with it it works withe setting viewcontroller only
thnx

Comment: Have you put the shouldRotate... method into your featureViewController's code?

Comment: featuresViewController does not have .h and .m files 
where to put that function?!!!

Comment: How are you creating featuresViewController? I imagine it must have some code?

Comment: From Apple - "By default, the UIViewController class displays views in portrait mode only." You'll need to write some code & override the shouldAutorotate... method as I suggested.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10112/discussion-between-moath-othman-aliwat-and-somaman)